# At the time / At a time / At the specific time

Tags: articles

Here's a context

I have a female friend and we used to have good feeling about each other, but we didn't end up becoming a couple. The problem was ...

> 1. Whenever we planed to meet 'at the time' we were supposed to meet, she was always late for the appointment.
> 2. Whenever we planed to meet 'at a time' we were supposed to meet, she was always late for the appointment.
> 3. Whenever we planed to meet 'at the specific time' we were supposed to meet, she was always late for the appointment.

I'm not sure which one is the most suitable one.

Comment: You've got an answer to the grammar question below, but I'd probably just say, "Whenever we planned to meet, she was always late."  (Planned, not planed.)

Answer (score 1):

Number 1 is correct, but it is unnecessarily long (and a little awkward):

> Whenever we planed to meet 'at the time' we were supposed to meet, she was always late for the appointment.

It would be more natural to say:

> Whenever we planed to meet, she was always late for the appointment.

Answer (score 0):

Number 1 is the correct sentence. The time has already been organised, so it uses "the" instead of "a".

Comment: But there's a "whenever". Whenever we planned to meet at *a* pre-arranged time...